# Auth0 with Vue not staying logged in after refresh on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, cookies, auth0

I am using Auth0 with a Vue application. Auth0 is acting strange and I have no idea where to begin.

If I am on a computer, then when switching pages in my app, the user gets logged out for a few seconds, the page loads and then Auth0 "loads" and logs the user back in. This is not desirable since it takes a few seconds to load up certain data on the page that only a user who is logged in should be able to see.

**But this is my main problem:**
On mobile devices, the user gets logged out when navigating to a new page within the app but the user never gets logged back in. Same thing happens when I refresh the page. The user gets logged out and I have to click the login button again.

Can't I make Auth0 work more efficiently where the user is immediately logged in when switching pages or never logged out in the first place?

**This is all of my relevant code:**

This is where Auth0 is imported into the app in `main.ts`:

```
import { createAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";
app.use(
  createAuth0({
    domain: 'SOME_DOMAIN.auth0.com',
    client_id: 'SOME_ID',
    audience: 'SOME_AUDIENCE',
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
    scope: 'openid'
  })
)
```

And then in each of the components that need to check if a user is logged in, I have this code:

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-vue'

  // only showing relevant code here
  setup() {
    const { user, isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0()
      return {
        user,
        isAuthenticated,
        getAccessTokenSilently
      }
  }
```

And this is pretty similar code here but this is in the header component (rendered on every single page in the app) and contains the login/logout buttons:

```
  setup() {
    const { user, isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently, loginWithRedirect, logout } = useAuth0()
      return {
        user,
        isAuthenticated,
        getAccessTokenSilently,
        login: () => {
          loginWithRedirect();
        },
        logoutUser: () => {
          logout({ returnTo: window.location.origin })
        }
      }
  },
```

So what am I missing? I need Auth0 to be more persistent. Am I missing some code?

Edit: not sure if this is important but this is how I navigate from one page to another:

```
router.push({ path: `/place/${store.selectedListView?._id}` })
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will guaranteed fix your issue (it might) but you should definitely be using navigation guards in vue-router instead of checking in each component if the user is logged in.  auth0 has some [documentation](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-vue#protect-a-route) about this

Comment: That does work for the pages that require authentication but some pages have certain components that should only show if authenticated and in that case, the components never load after refreshing

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with a similar problem using auth0 with react running on localhost. When I log in using loginWithRedirect(), auth0 places cookies on my browser but they would be cleared when I refresh the browser.

One solution to this was to enable 3rd party cookies for the localhost domain by going to browser settings, privacy and security, cookies and other site data, in "Sites that can always use cookies", add "http://localhost" and enable third party cookies for this site. This would let me stay logged in after reloading/refreshing.

However, I'm pretty sure there is a way to make this work without 3rd party cookies. I'll post it if found.

Comment: Keep me updated please

Comment: Actually I think you can use localstorage. What you may have to do is store a set of authentication keys to local storage (similar to what the cookie values would be) when you log in and then make your app look there first thing each time it loads and log in if found.

Comment: You'd want to clear it when user logs out so they won't be logged in automatically next time